# Difference between named urls in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

What is the difference between these two named urls in Django?

```
 re_path('articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/', views.year_archive),
 path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
```

They appear to do the same?

Comment: `<int:year>` accepts any integer value.

Comment: The regex in `re_path` is missing `^` and `$`, which might lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Alasdair ^$ is not needed if the re_path is in an included url.

Comment: Without the `^` and `$`, the regex will match `too/articles/2000/bar` as well as `articles/2000/`. It doesn’t matter whether it’s an included url or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `path` is a new style of url defining added in django 2.0 which has its own markup
- `re_path` is a more advanced method that requires you to write your own regex for the url. This is the method all url patterns used in django <= 1.11

if you using old style libraries in your django app you can use `re_path` instead of `url` of old version and if you creating new urls you can use either

Comment: re_path is not old style.  But please correct me if I am wrong thanks.

Comment: yes its new in django 2.0 but it uses  old style regex markup to define urls i mean that you need to use regex when using re_path

Comment: which one do I use?

Comment: use path it is more confortable to use

Comment: and flag this answer

Comment: @djangolearner: Use what you need. `<int:year>` obviously accepts values like `42` or `87654321`. If you want to make sure that a 4-digit value is entered you'll have to use a regular expression.

Comment: I see your point people path if I don't need the power of regex else re_path.